# Is it possible to create a subdomain served by tomcat based on a domain served by Apache on ASW ec2?

Tags: wordpress, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I'm new to web development. I'm planning to move my wordpress site to aws, says it's "example.com". I'm also planning to create a subdomain "xxx.example.com" using spring boot.  I'm wondering is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but remember only one process can only listen to a port (80 for http, 443 for https) in a machine.

Two options:

1. Have subdomain on a different machine with different IP address for it. So you can have Wordpress on one machine and your spring application on another.
2. Host in same machine and have one process (Apache, or a load balancer) listen to traffic for both and send it in appropriately. This is achieved with the ProxyPass command in Apache. Having a webserver in front of an application server is often recommended anyway as can be better for security and performance reasons.

There is a third option, which is to use a non-standard port (e.g. 8443) but that just makes your URL look messy (https://xxx.subdomain.com:8443). Which might be fine if you just want to test for your own sake but not great for production applications.